# iPhone app - Persistent hamburger menu vs last page visited

Tags: menu, iphone, back-button, hamburger

I'm wondering which option is best for an iPhone app using a hamburger menu (placed at the top left):

1. The menu is persistent on every single page even when the user goes
   to a sub-level.
2. When the user goes to a sub-level, the hamburger menu is replaced by a back button or a button whose label is the name of last page visited.
3. Both. The menu is persistent on every page and a back button appears when needed.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There's no way to answer this. It's entirely dependent on all of the unique factors of your particular app. The IA, the content, the functionality, the needs, the customer, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Always have your navigation persistent.

But that doesn't mean you can't have a "back" button in place when it's needed when you dig deeper on portions of the site.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbia3D.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Now this is just for the sake of your answer, but I highly suggest ***against*** the hamburger menu. Many products (twitter and Facebook to name a few) have moved away from the hamburger menu because of various reasons:

1. Discoverability was at an all time low
2. Not a lot of people understood what the hamburger menu was

They all placed a navigation element that was persistent on the bottom of the page, where people could toggle between what they knew were big hit points on the site (timeline, discover, messages, etc).

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I do agree with you, the bottom menu (always visible options) works better than the hamburger menu. However, I think the hamburger menu is a better option when you have many categories (equally important) and sub-categories.

Comment: Yeah it's a hard one honestly. Interesting point too about subcategories and categories that are equally important.

Comment: Persistent navigation is important only when it is. Sometimes it's not. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend iOS standards unless you really need to break from convention.  Standard iOS expectation is that you always have a back / up-level nav in the upper left corner. If you put 2 nav icons side-by-side in the upper left (Hamburger and Back Nav) that makes them both less usable and creates challenges - which is the one on the left most side?  Your #2 is the most common implementation.  Do users need to get back to the top most menu frequently enough to require having the hamburger nav on all screens? Then consider...

iOS standards also call for the use of the Tab Bar across the bottom - it is an option if you have a small (7) number of items in your nav (though it does persistently take up screen real-estate so isn't ideal unless the user needs to quickly access a few key screens).

The big question for any use of Hamburger Menus is... what are you putting in there?  @Majo0od incorrectly states the reasons why hamburger menus are problematic.  Hamburger menus have been being maligned considerably lately and most of the critiques have zero to do with user experience.  List Menus (Hamburger Menus) work great when they provide a consistent list of items clearly delineated.  The majority of user testing with List Menus shows that users very easily understand what they are and often go there to find stuff if the thing they're looking for isn't obvious elsewhere on the screen.  This has led to some bad practice among designers who started tossing everything in there - this leads to a garbage pile of items which makes it difficult for users to find what they're looking for or to know what to expect on subsequent visits to that menu.  A similar List Menu metaphor used all over both iOS and Android is 3 dots on the right (doesn't look like a hamburger so it isn't as maligned but has identical problems when not used consistently).  This is usually used to show a contextual list based on where the user is rather than an omnipresent top left list menu. Going back to my point for this paragraph... what are you using it for? Is it a clearly delineated list of concise items that is contextually relevant to where the user is in the app? Could it be better implemented using a different design pattern? Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score -1):

Use "back" button on sub-level pages and make menu accessible for the users with swipe gesture on all pages.

Comment: I don`t know if we understand each other. Hamburger menu icon is always visible on 1 level but menu is also accessible on every other level via swipe gesture. On sub-levels hamburger icon is replaced with back button.

Comment: Yeah I re-read your answer (and corrected myself). That's why I deleted what I wrote.

Comment: While this is an option, it's not backed up with arguments as to why it is better than what was suggestions.